# How to fire rest API from SQL

Tags: sql, rest, spring-boot, sql-server-2008

I want to fire a REST API(POST CALL) FROM SQL. i have created the following procedure to do the same. but facing issues regarding utl_http package getting denied because of  denied by access control list (ACL)

```
i have followed the steps mentioned in this article -

http://dbtricks.com/?p=159 

but still getting the below error - 

EXEC schedule_email
Error report -
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "P_STGATGCOMM.SCHEDULE_EMAIL", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
           Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.

below is my procedure

create or replace
procedure schedule_email AS PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
req utl_http.req;
res utl_http.resp;
url varchar2(4000) := 'http://localhost:8080/api/scheduleEmail';
name varchar2(4000);
buffer varchar2(4000);
content varchar2(4000) := '{"email":"sanjeev.rai@yopmail.com", "subject":"This isa subject", "body":"This isa body", "dateTime":"2019-09-03T15:20:00","timeZone":"Asia/Kolkata"}';
begin
req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1');
-- utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0');
utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json');
utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(content));
utl_http.write_text(req, content);
res := utl_http.get_response(req);
 -- process the response from the HTTP call
begin
    loop
utl_http.read_line(res, buffer);
    dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
    end loop;
    utl_http.end_response(res);
  exception
    when utl_http.end_of_body
    then
      utl_http.end_response(res);
  end;
end schedule_email;
```

Comment: I guess you need to give access through acl for sql.
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-application-development/page/integrate/custom-web-services/task/t_WbSvcRqACL.html

Comment: @Mark I have done that already begin
dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl (
acl => 'http_permissions.xml', -- or any other name
description => 'HTTP Access',
principal => 'P_STGATGCOMM', -- the user name trying to access the network resource
is_grant => TRUE,
privilege => 'connect',
start_date => null,
end_date => null
);

end;
begin
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl => 'http_permissions.xml',
principal => 'P_STGATGCOMM',
is_grant => true,
privilege => 'connect');
end;

Comment: @Mark BEGIN
dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl (
acl => 'http_permissions.xml',
host => 'LOCALHOST', /*can be computer name or IP , wildcards are accepted as well for example - '*.us.oracle.com'*/
lower_port => 80,
upper_port => 80
);

END;

BEGIN
dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl (
acl => 'http_permissions.xml',
host => 'LOCALHOST', /*can be computer name or IP , wildcards are accepted as well for example - '*.us.oracle.com'*/
lower_port => 80,
upper_port => NULL
);

END;

Comment: Have you executed this command ,
grant execute on utl_http to user;  can you verify in https://mohamedazar.com/2015/11/26/ora-24247-network-access-denied-by-access-control-list-acl/  all the steps you have perfomed.

Comment: @Mark i have executed below  in sysdba- GRANT EXECUTE ON utl_http TO P_STGATGCOMM;

GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_TCP  TO P_STGATGCOMM;
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_SMTP TO P_STGATGCOMM;

GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_http TO P_STGATGCOMM;  I have also done all steps mentionedd in https://mohamedazar.com/2015/11/26/ora-24247-network-access-denied-by-access-control-list-acl/ only difference is i have kept start_date as null while executing the scripts